# Debian set flutter variabile crash

Tags: linux, debian

Hi guys following the guide for install flutter on Linux i use  "export PATH="$PATH:/home/Dani/Downloads/flutter/bin"
and all ok flutter was visibile ..but until restart..i try to do permanent using sudo nano /etc/profile but when i add Path of flutter system going ti brick help

Answer (score 0):

Edit the first lines in your `/etc/profile` as follows:

```
if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then

PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
else
  PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/Dani/Downloads/flutter/bin"
fi
export PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

The Flutter SDK snap package provides everything needed to develop Flutter apps on your favorite Linux distribution. There's no need to install a bunch of development dependencies. Simply install the Flutter SDK snap and your favorite IDE and you're ready to start developing with Flutter.

To install Flutter SDK in Debian open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install snapd
```

Either log out and back in again, or restart your system, to ensure snap's paths are updated correctly.

Install Flutter:

```
sudo snap install flutter --classic
```

You may also be interested in these two other Flutter snap packages.

- flutter-gallery - a gallery of widgets and behaviors, plus demos and vignettes, all built with Flutter.
- flutter-ui-challenges - awesome Flutter UIs for real world applications with codes, free to use in your next flutter application.

If your code editor of choice is Visual Studio Code, run the following commands:

```
snap install code --classic  
code --install-extension dart-code.flutter
```